# Are Karthikeya and Mars same?

Tags: symbolism, astrology

I was recently watching a [documentary](http://youtu.be/t7EAlTcZFwY?t=46m30s) about symbolism in ancient culture on YouTube.

It proclaims that Karthiyeka and Mars are same, which per my information is a new concept. Can someone corroborate the claim? Does the story of Skanda tell such a comparison between the two seemingly separate gods?

Comment: No. Kartikeya is the reigning deity of the planet Mars.

Comment: @moonstar2001 would you like to put that as an answer and about the documentary in general?

Comment: Vineet - I don't have references that I can quote in the answer. It will be converted to a comment. Haven't watched the documentary but in general, I am skeptical of Westerners' interpretations of Indian wisdom as they tend to be reductive.

Comment: @moonstar2001 okay. fair enough. Might wait for someone else to answer it. Prima facie, it looks like citations would be available in Jyotisha texts.

Comment: There is a close link between mars and Karthikeya though .. the later is the over-ruling deity of mars..@Vineet

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**No, these two are not the same.**

Mangala is a graha (one of the Nava-grahas) while Kartikeya is a a form of God. I think the cause of the confusion is the use of the word 'Kumara' and 'shakti-hasta'in the pranama-mantra of Mangala, as these two are also adjectives of Lord Kartikeya :

> Dharani-garvasambhutam vidyutkanti-samaprabham/ kumaram shaktihascham cha mangalam pranamami aham. meaning : I bow down to Mangala, Who is son of Mother Earth, shining like electricity, boy/ youth ([kumara](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0&lang=sans&action=Search)) and holding 'and holding spear ([shakti, a kind of missile](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF&lang=sans&action=Search))

Lord Kartikeya is son of Mother Parvati. He is also depicted as Kumara and Kumara is one of His names (Reference:Kartikeya-Stotram, Stavakusumanjali, Ramakrishna Math, Nagpur, page 87) and holds a spear in His hand, especially in the Subrahmanya forms seen in the southern parts of India. Karikeya is depicted with bow and arrow in Bengal.

By the way, according to astrology, **the Adhi-Devata of Mangala or Mars is Skanda or Kartikeya** its Pratyadhidevata is his mother Kshiti (Reference: Jyotisha-Samirana).